# C++: ODBC Driver will not prompt

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

I am trying to figure out why ODBC connection to the database is not working, I wrote code (the top part) and commented out the source code of another program. That is working completely fine and the driver window pops up asking me to select the database / etc. I've been looking at this for over 20 mins now and my code (in my eyes) is COMPLETELY the same, but doesn't work. So I would like to have a fresh set of eyes to look at this and let me know if something is different than the commented out part.

Thanks <3

```
case IDB_LOGIN:{

            SQLHENV SQLEnviroment = NULL;
            SQLHDBC SQLConnection = NULL;

            if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &SQLEnviroment) != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (SQLSetEnvAttr(SQLEnviroment, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0) != SQL_SUCCESS)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQLEnviroment, &SQLConnection) != SQL_SUCCESS) {
                MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            }

            if (SQLDriverConnect(SQLConnection, GetDesktopWindow(), L"DRIVER={SQL DRIVER}; Server=LIVINGTREE; Database=Application Database;Uid=AdminNick;Pwd=spawn1234;", SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT) == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                MessageBox(NULL, L"Connected!", NULL, MB_OK);
            }


            //SQLHENV     hEnv = NULL;
            //SQLHDBC     hDbc = NULL;

            //SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
            //
            //SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3,0);

            //SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);

            //SQLDriverConnect(hDbc,
            //  GetDesktopWindow(),
            //  L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\\LIVINGTREE;Database=Application Database;Uid=AdminNick; Pwd=spawn123;",
            //  SQL_NTS,
            //  NULL,
            //  0,
            //  NULL,
            //  SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

            break;
        }
```

Comment: It would be worth your time to both 1) get the actual return value instead of testing for values you've picked out, and 2) call `SQlGetDiagRec` to determine the reason for the error.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx